# Generar automáticamente documento html con PHP

Tags: php, html, blog

Perdón por las molestias pero estoy bloqueado,

He creado una especie de portal para poder publicar artículos en una web tradicional, tipo `Wordpress` pero construyéndola desde cero.

El portal ya está conectado a mi base de datos mediante `PHP` y me está devolviendo perfectamente las vistas previas como quería, ahora viene el problema:

Quiero generar esos documentos que estoy viendo previamente a un archivo `html` para publicarlos en el sitio web de momento este es mi código.

```html
<?php
   date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid');
   include 'php/creator.php';
   include 'php/dbh.con.php';
   ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <title>Nuevo post</title>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cutive+Mono|Montserrat&display=swap" />
      <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="img/icon.png" />
      <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="img/icon.png" />
      <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="img/icon.png" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0" />
      <meta property="og:locale" content="en_US" />
      <meta property="og:type" content="editor" />
      <meta property="og:site_name" content="alex" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/creator.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/prism.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/emoji.css" />
      <script src="js/prism.js"></script>
      <meta property="og:site_name" content="Nuevo Post" />
      <meta property="og:title" content="Nuevo Post" />
      <meta property="og:description" content="Generador de Artículos para website/blog basado en Blogger o Wordpress" />
      <meta property="og:url" content="content_creator.php" />
   </head>
   <body>
      <section id="main-title">
         <div class="title">
            <h3><a href="index.html">&larr; Volver</a></h3>
            <h1> Álex Villalba - Editor de artículos</h1>
            <h2>
               Nuevo post - <script>var today = new Date();
                  var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
                  var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
                  var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
                  
                  today = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + yyyy;
                  document.write(today);
               </script>
            </h2>
         </div>
      </section>
      <section id="text-content">
      <div class="article">
         <?php
            echo "<form method='POST' action='".setArticle($art)."'>
            <input type='hidden' name='uid' value='Álex Villalba'>
            <input type='hidden' name='date' value='".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."'>
            <textarea cols='120' rows='27' name='message'></textarea><br><br>
            <button class='test' type='submit' name='postSubmit'>Vista previa</button>
            </form>"
            ;

            
            getArticles($art);

            ?>
      <br><br>       
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

y este es el archivo de configuración PHP,

```html
<?php

function setArticle($art) {
    if(isset($_POST['postSubmit'])) {
        $uid = $_POST['uid'];
        $date = $_POST['date'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];
        $sql = "INSERT INTO article (uid, date, message) VALUES ('$uid', '$date', '$message')";
        $result = $art->query($sql);
    }
}

function getArticles($art) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM article";
    $result = $art->query($sql);
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<br><br><div class='comment-box'><h2>";
        echo $row['uid']. "<br>";
        echo $row['date']. "<br><br></h2><p>";
        echo nl2br($row['message']);
        echo "</p>

        <form class='edit-form' method='POST' action='editcommnent.php>
        <input type='hidden' name='cid' value='".$row['cid']."'>
        <input type='hidden' name='uid' value='".$row['uid']."'>
        <input type='hidden' name='date' value='".$row['date']."'>
        <input type='hidden' name='message' value='".$row['message']."'>
        <button>Editar</button>
        </form>
        <form class='edit-form' method='POST' action='createArticle.php>
        <input type='hidden' name='cid' value='".$row['cid']."'>
        <input type='hidden' name='uid' value='".$row['uid']."'>
        <input type='hidden' name='date' value='".$row['date']."'>
        <input type='hidden' name='message' value='".$row['message']."'>
        <button>Publicar</button>
        </form>
        </div>"
        ;
    }
}
```

Soy nuevo con PHP y lo estoy haciendo todo sobre la marcha para ir aprendiendo, la cosa es que he estado mirando por la red y me he encontrado varios post de como hacerlo pero no lo acabo de ver claro, he visto algún fragmento de código y he llegado a la conclusión de que debería utilizar etiquetas **fwrite** pero no llego a entender como meter el **getArticles($art);** para poder generar directamente el documento con el formato que ya le he definido en el archivo de configuración,

perdón por el tostón pero he intentado ser lo más claro posible,

un saludo y gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Lo puedes hacer con una función simple:

Si tienes planeado guardar los documentos `html` en carpetas  ejemplo

```
"articulo1/estearticulo1.html"
```

```php
function escribirDocumento($carpeta,$archivo, $texto){
    $direccionDocumento = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/$carpeta/$archivo";
    if(!is_dir($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]. "/" . $carpeta)) mkdir($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]. "/" .$carpeta, 0777,true);
    file_put_contents($direccionDocumento, $texto);
    return 1;
}
```

La ejecutas de la siguiente manera:

```php
$texto = "Texto a escribir en este caso tu articulo";

escribirDocumento("mi_carpeta","nombre_documento.html", $texto);
```

**Notas:** Esta función solo sirve para directorios dinamicos de 1 nivel. Es decir  si tu dirección a guardar es:`"capertaExistente/carpetaDinamica/nombredocumento.html"`
o  si la direccion es `"carpetaExistente/nombredocumento.html"`

**Documentación:**

`$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]` : Obtiene la dirección RAIZ del sitio web.

`mkdir()` : Crea un directorio(carpeta) puedes asignar los permisos(0777)

`file_put_contents()`: Escribe el contenido de una variable en un documento, Si el documento no existe lo crea y si existe sustituye el contenido.

**Concejo que no has pedido:**  A medida que tu web crezca se hará más y más pesada con tanto documento `html` generado.

Te recomiendo crear una plantilla  y sustituir los contenidos dinámicamente. asi solo tendrás un único documento.

Para que esto sea `indexado` por `google`  utiliza `.htaccess` y un `sitemap`

Comment: Muchas gracias Wilfredo, ahora me pondré a ello, pero has dado en el clavo, mil gracias de nuevo ya me estaba desesperando